# how to write long (4byte) value to binary file in android

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a binary file header from java, and I had been using fixed values for the file size in the header.  That was easy:

```
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    os.write(0x36);//LSB
    os.write(0x10);
    os.write(0x0E);
    os.write(0x00);//MSB
```

But now I want to be more dynamic and write whatever size buffer I have to a file.  So I might get the size of my array as say 4054;  I want to take that and either break it apart and do four os.writes, or maybe there's a way to write it all at once.

OutputStream seems to only take one byte at a time, but I'd like to still use it as all the rest of my header code is already using it.

Comment: OutStream.write(byte[] bytes).   and friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), so you can control whether it writes LSB or MSB first.

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
buf.putLong(value);
os.write(buf.array());
```